# Prototyping Environment With Hg

Tags: mercurial

My team is running Mercurial hosted on our own server, and we ran into this issue:

We have a project called **Main Project**. In this project, there is a file called **Cool_Functions.code**. I needed to make some changes to **Cool_Functions.code** and bring it into my own **Prototyping Project**, which is more of a Proof of Concept.

The problem I have is that I don't necessarily want to commit **Prototyping Project** and my additions to **Cool_Functions.code** to the **Main Project** repository since it contains things that may just go away. Also, other team members might have their own Prototypes so creating a branch for each proof of concept would just mean creating a lot of eventually dead branches.

What are some strategies we can use in mercurial to be able to share our Prototyping projects?

Comment: You can make a branch, without having to share it if you don't want to. Clone your own repo from the shared repo, then don't push back your changes. If you want to push some things but not others, use the 'secret' phase to hide changesets.

Comment: The problem with not pushing is that then I can't share the changes. The problem with pushing is that it pollutes the Main Project with prototype branches.

Comment: People can pull directly from your clone, it doesn't have to go via the main repo. Could you put a clone each onto the server so you've effectively got your own fork each? You'd just have to be careful about what you pushed up to the main project repo.

Comment: It might also help to flag those clones as non-publishing repositories so you can strip stuff you no longer want to keep.  Once [changeset obsolescence](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ChangesetEvolution) hits stable, this will be much easier to do.